# In Ember.js app, where do I add jQuery to size a div according to browser size?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, zurb-foundation

I'm building an ember site using Zurb's Foundation.

I have my div.row class set to 100% width. And I have the following in my application template, application.hbs:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like my index template (homepage), index.hbs, to be the exact size of the browser so that I can give it a full width background image. I've done this lots of times, just never in an Ember app and I'm not sure where to put the jQuery.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $("#div1").width($(window).width());
});
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: have you tried putting it in your didInsertElement ? function of your view ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put it in the `didInsertElement` hook of you `index.hbs` corresponding `view` if you don't have one defined then do so:

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    $(window).resize(function(){
      $("#div1").width($(window).width());
    }); 
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! Should all jquery interactivity in the DOM be placed in the templates corresponding view?

Comment: @reknirt, normally yes, but if it's something more global handling different things then do it in your `ApplicationView` `didInsertElement` hook better